# Lax Milgram for non coercive problem?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, nonlinear-optimization

I obtained the variational form of my problem. and the bilinear form is below.

**Bilinear Form** Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an open set. For $u,v\in H^1_0(\Omega)$. I have 
$$a(u,v)=\int_\Omega u(t)v'(t)dt$$

By parts integration gives me $$\int_\Omega u(t)v'(t)dt=-\int_\Omega u'(t)v(t)dt$$ and I got that my $a$ is not coercive. So apparently I cant use the Lax-Milgram Theorem.

**Question**
I want to know if I can use any other technique in these circumsances? Or if there is any form of Lax-Milgram for non-coercive problem? I got some pdf. having a theorem like that but couldn't get any authentic reference for that. Thanking in Advance.

Comment: You should probably state exactly what you mean by "$a$ is coercive". Note however that from your second equation it follows $a(u,u)=0$  for any $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$

Comment: @PietroMajer thanks for your comment. Please let me add the definition.

Comment: Yes, this is the standard definition, and you already answered "No" in the computation between the first and second time you wrote the question

Comment: @PietroMajer Yes I realized it after your first comment. Thank you. I actually wanted you use Lax-Milgram for my problem. I have obtained $a(u,v)= <f,v>$ his form but my $a$ is not coercive. Is  there any other technique I can use in such situation to find the critical point of my variational form?

Comment: I suggest to edit and modify you original post, title included, stating clearly the new question :)

Comment: @PietroMajer I changed it on your suggestion. I hope it works now :)

Comment: Note that a bounded bilinear form $a(u,v)$ on a Hilbert space is of the form $(Tu,v)$, for a unique bounded operator $T$ on $H$. In this case $Tu(x)=\int_0^xu(t)dt-\Big(\int_0^1u(t)dt\Big)x$.

Comment: @PietroMajer can you please little elaborate it? I am not able to make $(Tu,v)=a(u,v)$.

Comment: Why shouldn't I take $Tu=u'$ so that $(Tu,v)=a(u,v)$?  Isn't $T$ is linear nad bounded for $H^1_0(\Omega)$$?.

Comment: $(Tu,v)$ here must be the $H^1_0$ product. Besides, $u\mapsto u'$ is only bounded as operator from $H^1_0 $ to $L^2$

Comment: Can you please do me a favor of explaining $(Tu,v)$ for $T$ you just mentioned? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: $$(Tu,v):=\int_0^1(Tu)'v'dx=\int_0^1uv'dx=a(u,v)$$ because $\int_0^1v'dx=0$. The Linear term in the definition of T Is needed to make it $H_0^1$ valued

Comment: Thank you so much :). Now I got that. Can you please provide your email? In case of acknowledging your efforts in my results?

Comment: You're welcome, don't mention it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97045/discussion-between-user786-and-pietro-majer).

Comment: Just a comment about the (im)possibility of using non-coercive variants of Lax-Milgram: coercivity asbolutely cannot be removed. To see this consider the null bilinear form $a(u,v)=0$, which is as nice as it gets in terms of continuity or whatever additional regularity one may think of requiring for a putative variant of the statement. For any linear form $L$ it is pretty clear that solving $a(u,v)=L(v)$ is absolutely hopeless in general (unless $L$ is zero). So no, there can be no Lax-Milgram like without coercivity.